3DOF robot in Moveit2
I've successfully imported a 3 DOF SCARA bot via the Moveit2 setup assistant. While I can set a random valid pose in RViz, and plan path and execute, I can't move the end effector to a desired pose. The interactive marker exists and can be rotated, but it cannot be translated.
As a next step, when I was following this tutorial, I ran into a problem. In the tutorial, a pose is specified for the end effector, and a path is planned and executed. When I try this with my robot, I get the error:
/src/ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/src/RRTConnect.cpp:252  Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree

I've verified that the given poses were valid. When I set random joint values using this instead of pose, I get the robot working. But what I'd like is the ablility to input pose, instead of joints' values -- I want IK to be handled by Moveit.
Going through some of the answers, I encountered suggestions like it may be goal tolerance, or could be that the IK solvers aren't good at robots with < 6 DOFs. While I've tested with higher goal tolerances with no success, I'm skeptical that the solvers aren't good for robots < 6 DOFs.
I'd really appreciate if someone can point out the exact issue and direct me to a solution. If you need more specifics, please let me know. Thanks!


Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree

This error usually means that IK failed to find a valid solution for one of the intermediate points between start and goal. A 3DOF arm is going to have a huge number of EEF poses that it can never reach.
You may have more success asking for a "position only" trajectory (i.e. you're saying that you don't care what the EEF orientation is.) If this also fails, try giving the planner more execution time.

My EEF currently only has a z-motion - it's a revolute joint. I'll try giving planner more execution time.
